# Ruby Regular expression match

Tags: ruby, regex

why this regexp

```
(?<!\S)[^\s]*[aeiou][^\s]*(?<=\d)(?!\S)
```

match test123 but not 123test

i want to match a word which must have a vowel and digit .As i am new to this i dont understand all methods completely. maybe thats causing problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to match a word which must have a vowel and digit

```
(?<!\S)\S*(?:[aeiou]\S*\d|\d\S*[aeiou])\S*(?!\S)
```

This part in your regex,

```
(?<=\d)(?!\S)
```

will look for a digit to be present which must not be followed by a non-space character. In this `test123`, because 3 present at the last satisfies this condition where 3 is not followed by a non-space character. So your regex matches `test123` and fails to match `123test` because all the digits present in this input is followed by a non-space character. And also your regex asserts that there must be an vowel exists before the digit. This is also a reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\S)[^\s]*[aeiou][^\s]*(?<=\d)(?!\S)

                          ^^^^^^^
```

Because of the `lookbehind` which makes regex engine look for `integer` after the last match which is not present in `123test`

For your needs you can simply use

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[aeiou])[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/27

Comment: It is not an appropriate explanation. `(?<=\d)` is not checking for a digit at the end since it is a *look-behind*.

Comment: @stribizhev when regex engine matches the last character it checks if it is digit or not.

Comment: @stribizhev the lookbehind is placed after consuming the last character.So once the match is complete then regex enigne tries to lookfor integer.In short the last match should be a digit

Comment: I mean this part *after the last match* is not appropriate. It checks *before*.

Comment: @stribizhev the regex engine will do it after the last match is consumed.Please use `regex101.com` and watch debugger perfomr

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way of doing this:

```
def vowel_and_num?(str)
 !(str.scan(/[aeiou]/).empty? || str.scan(/[0-9]/).empty?)
end

vowel_and_num?("test123")
# => true

vowel_and_num?("123test")
# => true

vowel_and_num?("test")
# => false

vowel_and_num?("123")
# => false
```